# Teamcity build status icon on github: No permission to get data

Tags: github, teamcity, github-flavored-markdown

I try to represent Teamcity build status of project on its Github README.md page.
For this purpose I use TeamCity rest API that exposes status icon at URL

```
&lt;teamcity-root&gt;/app/rest/builds/buildType:%28id:&lt;buildTypeID&gt;%29/statusIcon
```

For now I have two Github projects and three TeamCity builds for them (separate builds for two branches).

For all three builds URL built by scheme mentioned above gives me expected image. But Github website replaces original image paths from my TeamCity by own paths from github-camo.global.ssl.fastly.net host. And for two from three builds instead of image I expect to see (success or fail) I get image stating 'No permission to get data'. (It doesn't depend on way I insert image into file: with markdown syntax or inline HTML)

Both Github projects are private. TeamCity site requires login in general but status icons don't.

I've checked also that this situation doesn't depend on TeamCity service hook usage.

I'll be glad to hear any idea on subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was not related to Github. It appears that Status Widget was not enabled for builds in question and in such situation status icon requires login. Enabling the widget solves the problem

Answer (score 6):

The settings is in

Project -> Build Configuration Settings -> General Settings -> "enable status widget"

See [Teamcity build badge on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548247/teamcity-build-badge-on-github/39603836#39603836)