# Teamcity build badge on github

Tags: github, teamcity

I wanted to add a teamcity build badge on my github page.My repository is a private github repository.
I started of by including the code below as the [link](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2012/07/teamcity-build-status-icon/) said.

```
<a href="http://teamcity/viewType.html?buildTypeId=myID&guest=1"> 
<img src="http://teamcity/app/rest/builds/buildType(id:myID)/statusIcon"/>
</a>
```

The problem I got stuck at then,was that the image was being blocked.I suspected that this was because my teamcity server was on http while my github repo used https.

In my case it is not possible to change teamcity to use https and so this was not an option.

Any workarounds/suggestions for how to get my build badges on github?

Answer (score 13):

Make sure to check "enable status widget" checkbox on the General Setting page:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

> For anyone looking for the markdown link syntax of the TeamCity build badge, here it is:

```
[![Build Status](http://teamcity/app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:myID)/statusIcon)](http://teamcity/viewType.html?buildTypeId=myID&guest=1)
```

Comment: Which `myId` is that? The `Build configuration ID` perhaps, or some sort of external ID? Also, I would assume guest user login access is required?

Comment: The ID is the `Build configuration ID`. Guest access is required.

Answer (score 2):

For the user pages displayed, GitHub retrieves the images from the server side and replaces the original image with the one cached. That is why, the TeamCity instance should be accessible externally and the status icon should be available to any user: the easiest way to ensure that is to check "enable status widget" as Boris suggested.

The image is also cached quite aggressively by GitHub, so the badge shown can be outdated. Use at least TeamCity 10.0.2 which has added HTTP headers trying to prevent that caching.

Comment: I have enabled the status widget button.Also,I have checked that the url which I have used in my source is externally accessible.My teamcity version is 9.1.5.Can this be the issue?

Comment: Also another weird thing I noticed was that the github badge was coming up in the readme when I switched to mobile view in my browser and would disappear again when I switch to normal browser mode.Also in my network tab,I observed that the image is being blocked(blocked:mixed-content) in my normal browser mode while it has a status of 200(OK) in the mobile mode.Any clues as to why this might be happening?

Comment: "blocked:mixed-content" probbaly means that the image is included via http:// while the main page is https://
That does not happen when GitHub renders README.md (as GitHub rewrites/caches the image), so you are probbaly viewing raw html where you need to use https:// for the image from the TeamCity server.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the Github camo cache as long you have control over the Headeres of the image.
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-anonymized-urls#an-image-that-changed-recently-is-not-updating

But Github is not able, because they anonymize the Ressource, to handle private URLs/Hosts.
This is written here: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-anonymized-urls#viewing-images-on-private-networks